# Unable to run a manage.py command from app/views.py via subprocess

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04, django-manage.py

Python/Django newbie here!

In my new project, I am able to load the django template pages and the admin section, as well as update and delete things from the admin... I've been able to collectstatic without a problem and I can also run all commands with manage.py from bash, all from inside virtualenv.

Where I am stuck is trying to run a "python manage.py check" from the app's views.py via subprocess, for example:

some_app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import subprocess
import shlex

def home(request):
    cmd = 'python manage.py check'
    subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
    return HttpResponse("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>")
```

The HTML "Hello World" loads fine, the subprocess command results in Apache error:

```
"python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

"python: can't open file '../myweb/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".
```

I am not sure I know why this is, here's the file structure I have:

- /var/www/project (venv)

  - bin/
  - include/
  - lib/
  - share/
  - myweb/

    - db.sqlite3
    - manage.py
    - myweb/
    - some_app/

      - views.py
      - ect...
    - tatic/
    - templates/

If enyone has any tips I would appreciate it!

setup info:

- Ubuntu server 18.04
- Apache 2.4.29
- virtualenv w/python 3.6.7
- Django2.2.1

Comment: Don't do this. Use [`call_command()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django.core.management.call_command).

Answer (score 0):

**You have to declare the correct relative path**

some_app/
    views.py (YOU ARE HERE)
project_name/
    manage.py (YOU HAVE TO GO HERE)

So it becomes:

```
def home(request):
    cmd = 'python ../project_name/manage.py check'
    subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
    return HttpResponse("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>")
```

Or Simply:

> As Daniel Roseman wrote in his comments

```
call_command('check')
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have tried this approach unsuccessfully.

Comment: /var/www/project/myweb/manage.py next to db.sqlite3 as shown above